# Jenkins - Build, Deploy and Promote

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins

Recently, I started learning how to use Jenkins CI. So I am a little bit of a noob at jenkins. I am about to start to try and do the following:

1. I have setup a maven multi-module job on jenkins, which builds, tests, and finally creates 4 seperate war applications. I archive the war artifacts as part of this job. These war files will only ever be built once, they contain multiple environment properties, and the war file along with each environments server will manage the profile it runs in, eg dev, test, staging, prod, etc
2. I have another job on jenkins which will deal with the deployment to multiple environments.
   This second job, uses the copy artifact plugin, and uses a post build action to deploy to a dev environment.
3. The job in step 2 will hopefully be able to have multiple promotions, allowing deployment to multiple environments: test/staging/performance/production etc.

I have searched stackoverflow and google, and all the posts I see, always use the parameterized plugin, specifying a parameter for the environment. This means there is a seperate build for each env which I don't like.

Can anyone tell me if this is the right way to go? Or direct me to some tutorial on how to do this properly.

Comment: Jenkins is a great CI server, but it's not designed for deployment or pipelines; one suggestion I'd have is to take a look at Inedo's [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster/overview), which can deploy artifacts right out of Jenkins, is a bit easier to set up, and also has other features which may come in handy down the line like approvals, etc. Disclaimer: I am a dev at Inedo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the jenkins configuration. I have this working very nicely now.

In the deployment job, I didn't see the "Add another promotion process" button, which allows me to promote the same build to multiple environments manually or automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you need is a [matrix-project build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project).

P.S.
A good introduction to Jenkins could be found in [Jenkins: The Definitive Guide](http://www.wakaleo.com/books/jenkins-the-definitive-guide)

Comment: I think that is a bit overkill for what I need. I only want one build that will be deployed to multiple environments.